# Dropping voltage from battery supply for low current application

Tags: diodes, circuit-design, low-power, battery-operated

My battery might supply 3.7 V, while absolute maximum for an IC it is supplying is 3.55 V and lowest operating voltage is 2.65 V. The IC is at sleep most of the time, consuming 10 nA. Every now and then <1 % of it's lifetime it wakes up to consume 1 mA. Voltage could be dropped with a series (Schottky) diode. Here are curves for I-V curves for forward currents at different temperatures from Toshiba CUS10S30 Schottky diode datasheet:

[image]

But only if it was always 25 C and current draw would be stable. I do need to make a sacrifice to one way or the other, but adding an LDO regulator type of a device would drain the battery fast. How do I achieve not damaging the IC and only sacrificing ~tens of % of battery life?

Comment: What is your battery that has max 3.7V? Can you drop more voltage with a standad diode or LED? What is the chip with 3.55 maximum voltage, what is the nominal maximum, can you provide datasheet?

Comment: What's the lowest supply the chip can use?

Comment: Battery: Li-SOCl2 chemistry with elevated temperature. Regardless of manufacturer to meet other spec I run into the problem. The rest of the circuit I simplified by saying it's one IC, it's actually a more complicated module with one pin being problematic. I do get frustrated too when there is no actual circuit in the posting, but it would have over-complicated the matter by a lot, so I tried to explain the situation well. And it is one pin in a module and the module MFG refuses to give any extra info than what I put in the question and the main datasheet is no help.

Comment: @Andyaka lowest state the chip goes to is 10 uA (by the little spec I was able to get). When it operates it uses 1 mA.

Comment: @Andyaka you probably meant voltage: 2.65 V. I'll add that critical information in the question.

Comment: can you use a different diode type? you have about 1v of wiggle room.

Comment: Yes and the battery chemistry is quite suitable. Except that in low temperatures the downsides accumulate, so I'd rather stay on the lower side of voltage drop. Also to my suprise not everyone give specs to low current applications in datasheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with using a really low quiescent current LDO regulator like [this one](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005623B.pdf): -

[image]

It sounds like the 2.8 volt version might suit.

[Here's a few more](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/products/power-management/dc-dc-converters-and-voltage-regulators/linear-ldo-voltage-regulators/low-quiescent-current-ldo-regulators#).

Comment: I seemed to have messed up the units in the question for sleep more, it was actually 10 nA, not 10 uA, sorry. This is a great answer nevertheless. I might be able to use the rest of my circuit to take use of the 1 nA Shutdown Supply Current too.